# Where to ask about handling deployment of ASP.NET MVC, VSO, Azure/Self Hosted

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I normally frequent SO but I have a general question on handling application deployment with database changes.  What would be the best place to ask this question?

Comment: I can't be sure without a few more details, but I think your question could be on topic on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). You can try asking in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/21/the-whiteboard), the regulars there are always happy to help shape questions to be more in line with our general guidelines.

Comment: You can ask on https://dba.stackexchange.com/